# Typescript and async calls

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am working with TypeScript and I want to make an async call to a rest service.

I want to ensure that the rest call has finished before moving forward.

I have "cobbled" together this code but I am unsure if it is correct or the best way to accomplish this task.

Can anyone please take a look and provide feedback? I am just deleting a record and I want to return a boolean indicating if the call was successful or not.

thanks in advance

```
async SubmitRESTRequest() {

            var response: boolean;

            await new Promise(next => {

                try {
                    var promise = $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://mywebsite/deleteperson/1',                                                
                        type: 'DELETE'
                    }).then(function (data) {
                        response = true;
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        next();                        
                    }).fail(function (data) {
                        response = false;
                        next();
                    });
                }
                catch (err) {
                    response = false;
                    next();
                }
            });

            return response;

        }
```

I am calling the code via the following code

```
var wardResponse:Boolean = await SubmitRESTRequest();
```

Comment: What happens when you run this--does it work? If it doesn't work, please describe what isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: Your code can be reduced to the following: `var result = $.ajax({ url, type: 'delete' }).then(() => true).catch(() => false)`. 90% of it is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned from `$.ajax` is close enough to a promise that you can `await` it. You're doing a bunch of unnecessary stuff (and using an antipattern) by wrapping a promise-oid inside the `Promise` constructor, and you're almost entirely defeating the purpose of using `async`/`await`.

Give this a try. It's much cleaner and should work at least as well as what you have there:

```
async SubmitRESTRequest() {
  try {
    await $.ajax({
      url: 'https://mywebsite/deleteperson/1',
      type: 'DELETE'
    });
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```